# Por qué este entorno Docker en azure no usa el .env?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, docker

Hola amigos estoy subiendo unos un contenedor Docker a azure y lo hago todo muy bien, me funciona y todo cuando hago el build se crea la imagen correctamente pero cuando hago push a un servidor linux que esta en azure este tiene un problema y es que no toma la data del .env

Cabe destacar que si me funciona localmente todo e incluso sube la imagen todo correctamente pero donde tiene el problema es en el .env

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí dejo mi configuración docker.

```
FROM node:16-slim

USER node

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app


COPY --chown=node package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY --chown=node . .

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000

EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD [ "node", "." ]

WORKDIR /home/node/app/src
```

Comment: no se si tenga que ver pero en mi .gitignore tengo puesto que ignore el .env pero es en el .gitignore en el .dockerignore evidentemente no pongo el .env

Comment: El archivo`.env` se usa para variables de entorno locales. Tus variables de entorno en producción debes declararlas en el servidor, no deben ser cargadas desde ningún fichero, esto por motivos de seguridad. Es por ello que el fichero `.env` se añade a `.gitignore` para no persistir el mismo en el repositorio. Piensa que diferentes desarrolladores pueden tener diferentes variables de entorno para el mismo proyecto. Saludos